# Quiero hacer un conversor de binario a decimal, hexadecimal y a octal

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando crear un conversor entre todas las opciones que existe de decimal, binario, hexadecimal y octal, por ahora he hecho el de decimal a todos los demás, usando toString(), pero a la hora de hacer el de binario al resto, no lo logro... he buscado informacion en todos lados y no he encontrado nada... lo unico que he sacado es esto:

```
    var numero = 111;
    var posicion = 0;
    var sumaTotal;
    var longitud = numero.length;
    for (longitud; posicion <= longitud; posicion++) {
        var char = numero.charAt(posicion);
        if (char == 1) {
            var pos = char * 2 ^ posicion;
            sumaTotal += pos;
            posicion++;
        } else {
            posicion++;
        }
    }
    alert(sumaTotal);
```

Pero no funciona, se salta el for completamente... llevo varios días con este proyecto y no lo logro, si alguien conoce una función que resuelva este problema por favor decidmelo.
Gracias de antemano.

Esto es lo que use para calcular de decimal a binario:

```
result = (+numero).toString(2)
```

Un saludo

Comment: No sé si lo haces por hacer el ejercicio, pero en estos casos lo habitual es hacer conversores de y hacia un formato común. Por ejemplo, tienes conversores de binario a decimal (y viceversa) y de decimal a octal, el conversor de binario a octal entonces es una llamada del conversor de binario a decimal seguida de una llamada del conversor de decimal a octal.

Comment: Si quieres convertir entre bases, si no es decimal, aun asi es mas facil primero pasarlo a decimal y luego convertirlo a otra base.

Comment: Entiendo, y donde puedo encontrar conversores?, o crear alguno?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

la variable `numero` esta declarada como un numero (type `number`), por lo que no posee la propiedad `.length` ni `.charAt()`. Debes transformarlo a string o declararlo como tal:

```
var numero = "111"; // o numero=parseInt(111)
var posicion = 0;
var sumaTotal;
var longitud = numero.length;
for (longitud; posicion <= longitud; posicion++) {
   var char = numero.charAt(posicion);
   ...
)
```

**Nota:**

Ya existe una implementacion para convertir un binario, octal o hexadecimal a entero, usando `parseInt( expr, base)`, de manera analoga a como haces la conversion usando `Number.toString(base)`

```
parseInt("111",2); // binario 7
parseInt("FF",16); // hexa 255
parseInt("17",8); // octal 15
```

Finalmente, las conversiones se pueden llevar a cabo usando Number(value).toString(base), parseInt(value,base), o una combinacion de ambas. Por ejemplo, para binario a hexadecimal

```
Number(parseInt(11111111,2)).toString(16); // 1111111 => FF
```

Lo que reduciria las conversiones a una funccion como esta:

```
function convert(value,sourceBase,targetBase){
    return Number(parseInt(value,sourceBase)).toString(targetBase);
}
convert(11111111,2,16); // FF
convert(255,10,16); // FF
```

**Nota:** La salida de esta funcion siempre sera string, por lo que se puede usar parseInt() o Number() para convertirlo a numero si se necesita.

Comment: Okay, pero tengo una duda de poner parseInt... en donde escribes el numero ya sea binario, hexadecimal, octal, o lo que sea... tengo que escribir un numero o puedo meter una variable con un string metido para que funcione?, por ejemplo;

    var numero = "111";
    parseInt(numero,2); // binario 7

funcionaria asi?

Comment: Claro funciona con cualquier valor o variable, incluso si fuera numero, se recibira sin problemas `parseInt("111", 2) == parseInt(111, 2)`

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: De hecho se me acaba de ocurrir otra duda... probando he visto que lo del parseInt sirve para pasar a decimal lo que escribas, entonces... existe algun metodo similar para pasar de hexadecimal a octal por ejemplo, o de octal a binario, lo que quiero decir, entre decimal, binario, hexadecimal y octal, que no sean de decimal a x, o de x a decimal... como puedo hacer el resto de las 8 opciones restantes?
Perdon po molestar y gracias.

Comment: Todas son o una llamada a parseInt, a Number.toString,  o a una combinacion de ambas. Agrego un ejemplo

Comment: Lo siento por seguir molestando pero no me funciona el parseInt añadiendo una variable, comparto el codigo que he usado a ver si encuentras algun error, antes de nada te pongo en contexto del programa que estoy creando... Estoy haciendo un conversor, (como supongo que es evidente), entonces he hecho un teclado con html pero al escribir 111 y presionar el boton de conversion de binario a decimal me devuelve NaN. 

´
    case "bd": 
    fin = parseInt(result.textContent, 2); 
    break;
`

el case "bd": significa binario-decimal, por si habia duda

Comment: Si result es un elemento de tipo `<input>` mejor usa result.value. En cualquier otro caso, esta entregando `NaN` por que *no es convertible a numero* (puede estar vacio o no ser un binario valido con solo `0`s y `1`s)

Comment: Comprendo, ya lo he arreglado todo, muchas gracias